# Stripping stray ANSI escape sequences from eshell

Tags: eshell

I can't seem to identify this color sequence. I have enabled ansi colors successfully (to test, ls shows colored output), however a strange thing happens when I attempt to run `npm` and I can't identify the kind of colors these are, or how to make it so eshell can show them. The output is as follows

```
Usage npm <command>
... <remainder of usage here>
npm @ 3.3.10 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
^[[?25h^[[0G^[[?25h^[[0G~/my/directory/that/i/am/in $
```

I have tried to look for things like "non-ansi color codes" and "npm color codes" and none of them have pointed me in the correct direction.

Can anyone identify these colors and help me figure out how to display them properly?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I have identified these as unicode sequences. I have added everything in:

https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/working-coding-systems-unicode-emacs

as well as the following code for Eshell specifically:

```
(defun set-buffer-utf8 ()
   (set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8 'utf-8)
 )
 (add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook 'set-buffer-utf8)
```

This does not work. I have also tried this with the modes `utf-16` and `mule-utf-8` with no luck.

Also, if I type

`echo $LANG` I get `en_US.UTF-8`. `echo $LC_ALL` also returns `en_US.UTF-8`.

**EDIT 2:**

I have now tried to set the encoding of eshell (in the hook above) to `iso-8859-7` and `iso-8859-1` with no luck.

Comment: These are most certainly not related to colors.

Comment: I have seen it uses some kind of utf symbols to show the branches and sub-dependencies. It may be the character selection jointly with the color. Is your terminal utf-8?

Comment: @DiegoSevilla This is EShell so im not actually sure.

Comment: @DiegoSevilla I have added the stuff specified here: https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/working-coding-systems-unicode-emacs and it has not fixed it.

Comment: This is not encoding-related either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There's a huge amount of ANSI escape sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.txt).  I've made a regex catching most you'll run into based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python/33925425#33925425) and wrote some code to use it with eshell:

```
(defvar my-ansi-escape-re
  (rx (or ?\233 (and ?\e ?\[))
      (zero-or-more (char (?0 . ?\?)))
      (zero-or-more (char ?\s ?- ?\/))
      (char (?@ . ?~))))

(defun my-nuke-ansi-escapes (beg end)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char beg)
    (while (re-search-forward my-ansi-escape-re end t)
      (replace-match ""))))

(defun my-eshell-nuke-ansi-escapes ()
  (my-nuke-ansi-escapes eshell-last-output-start eshell-last-output-end))

(add-hook 'eshell-output-filter-functions 'my-eshell-nuke-ansi-escapes t)
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I noticed you said it is not encoding related. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Given the lack of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) and the presence of sequences suspiciously looking like ANSI escapes, I am fairly sure this is not a problem to solve by changing the buffer encoding and investigated Emacs' ANSI escape support instead.